# Laravel rendering a partial view without html tags and header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to render a view with only html codes with NONE of them `<html><head></head><body>`... tags because I want to return the code with AJAX and append it to another view, making it into a modal. I want to keep these modals in separate templates instead of having it all in one page. Is there a way in Laravel or can I only do it my own way?

Controller:

```
public function new() {
    return View('modals.new');
}
```

This is what I plan to do with the rendering in AJAX:

```
function(url, selector) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
         $(body).append(data);
    })
    $(selector).modal();
}
```

Right now it's rendering with the full html/head/body tags. Would I have to strip out the tags on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can manipulate the full page received and only insert parts of it

```
function(url, selector) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
         var $contentWanted = $(data).find(selector);
         $(body).append($contentWanted);
    })
    $(selector).modal();
}
```